# C# Socket ReceiveAsync

Tags: c#, sockets, asyncsocket

I am used to sync sockets and had a few headaches to get to the point where I am now, especially with `Socket.Receive(..)` not always receiveing all bytes

Here is my code what I used to use

```
    public byte[] Receive(int size)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        var r = 0;
        do
        {
            // ReSharper disable once InconsistentlySynchronizedField
            var c = _clientSocket.Receive(buffer, r, size - r, SocketFlags.None);
            if (c == 0)
            {
                throw new SocketExtendedException();
            }
            r += c;
        } while (r != buffer.Length);
        return buffer;
    }
```

Now I started to use sockets in Windows Phone BUT `.Receive(..)` is not available and I managed to get `Socket.ReceiveAsync(..)` working but I am concerned (no problems happened so far) here is my new code, I have not implemented the checking if all bytes has been recieved or not nor do I know if I have to with the following code

```
    private byte[] ReadBySize(int size = 4)
    {
        var readEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        var recieveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
        {
            UserToken = readEvent
        };
        recieveArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, size);
        recieveArgs.Completed += recieveArgs_Completed;
        _connecter.ReceiveAsync(recieveArgs);
        readEvent.WaitOne();

        if (recieveArgs.BytesTransferred == 0)
        {
            if (recieveArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                throw new SocketException((int)recieveArgs.SocketError);
            throw new CommunicationException();
        }
        return buffer;
    }

    void recieveArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        var are = (AutoResetEvent)e.UserToken;
        are.Set();
    }
```

This is my first use of `ReceiveAsync` can someone point out anything I might have done wrong or need to change

Comment: I would suggest using `BeginReceive()`

Comment: In windows Phone BeginRecieve and Recieve is not available, I have used BeginReceive aswell but its not available, I can only use StreamSocket or Socket (with RecieveAsync)

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, did not read it was windows phone.

Comment: Are you using TCP? Have you considered using `TcpClient`/`TcpListener` if that is the case? `NetworkStream` is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: unfortunatly TcpClient also not available in Windows Phone

Comment: See my answer, I went and force the Server to not send all bytes to the client if you were interested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok I went and took a large buffer and send it in batches with a sleep interval in between to replicate 'not all bytes received' So my code above doesn't recieve all bytes. for those who also use ReceiveAsync(..) here is my code that works

```
    private byte[] ReadBySize(int size = 4)
    {
        var readEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var buffer = new byte[size]; //Receive buffer
        var totalRecieved = 0;
        do
        {
            var recieveArgs = new SocketAsyncEventArgs()
            {
                UserToken = readEvent
            };
            recieveArgs.SetBuffer(buffer, totalRecieved, size - totalRecieved);//Receive bytes from x to total - x, x is the number of bytes already recieved
            recieveArgs.Completed += recieveArgs_Completed;
            _connecter.ReceiveAsync(recieveArgs);
            readEvent.WaitOne();//Wait for recieve

            if (recieveArgs.BytesTransferred == 0)//If now bytes are recieved then there is an error
            {
                if (recieveArgs.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
                    throw new ReadException(ReadExceptionCode.UnexpectedDisconnect,"Unexpected Disconnect");
                throw new ReadException(ReadExceptionCode.DisconnectGracefully);
            }
            totalRecieved += recieveArgs.BytesTransferred;

        } while (totalRecieved != size);//Check if all bytes has been received
        return buffer;
    }

    void recieveArgs_Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        var are = (AutoResetEvent)e.UserToken;
        are.Set();
    }
```

The way I work with my Socket applications is to send a Buffer that consist of some variables

```
[0] -> 0,1,2 0 is keep alive, 1 means there are data, 2 means a type off error occured
[1,2,3,4] size of the actual buffer I am sending
[x(size of 1,2,3,4)] the actual 'Serialized' data buffer
```

Comment: Why are you even using async APIs if you're effectively making them synchronous by calling `ReceiveAsync` then `WaitOne` in the same thread?  You could just call the synchronous, blocking `Receive()`.

Comment: Because this was 2 years ago and it was windows phone, windows phone does not have Recieve() if you've read the question you would have seen that. I needed it synchronous at that time.
Today the code looks a lot different

Comment: Thank you, I did indeed miss that part. I would have never guessed that the sync api would be unavailable.

Comment: :) My code now contains `TaskCompletionSource<byte[]>()`, getting rid of the ugly `AutoResetEvent` and I now  make use of `async/await`, `byte[]` has become `Task<byte[]>` and `return buffer` has become`return tcs.Task;`, `recieveArgs_Completed` also changed to accomodate TaskCompletionSource

Comment: @DonaldJansen could you update your answer to your latest comment? Would be great to see an `async/await`  implementation! 

Answer (score 1):

You could create a socket extension like:

```
public static Task<int> ReceiveAsync(this Socket socket,
    byte[] buffer, int offset, int size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
{
    if (socket == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(socket));

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
    socket.BeginReceive(buffer, offset, size, socketFlags, ar =>
    {
        try { tcs.TrySetResult(socket.EndReceive(ar)); }
        catch (Exception e) { tcs.TrySetException(e); }
    }, state: null);
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

And then a method to read the size you want like this:

```
public static async Task<byte[]> ReadFixed(Socket socket, int bufferSize)
{
    byte[] ret = new byte[bufferSize];
    for (int read = 0; read < bufferSize; read += await socket.ReceiveAsync(ret, read, ret.Length - read, SocketFlags.None)) ;
    return ret;
}
```